# Is there a way to use dynamic "mentions" in a rich text field using scripting in Quick Base?

Tags: quickbase

In our QuickBase project management app, users have the ability to start a discussion thread on any project or task. Is it possible to add the ability for dynamic user mentions within the Rich Text or plain textarea fields? Is there a way to add scripting within QuickBase to make this possible?

For example, if I am typing a message and want to mention someone's name prefaced by the "@" symbol (e.g. **@Gian Dough**), it would detect a user's name, recognize the mention and send an alert to the person that their name was mentioned in this discussion. To further demonstrate what I want it to look like, check out the live jQuery example at  https://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

I can't find any documentation on this and the core platform doesn't seem to have this functionality built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a native Quick Base feature for this, but with Quick Base's custom code pages and web hooks a developer could add this as custom functionally to your Quick Base app.

Comment: Thanks @Erich! I'm going to look into a coding solution for this.